# Change the dropdown menu list item square

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

I coulnd find a proper name and phrase for this to explain, so here's a picture:

[image]

I'd like to change the white area's as shown above in the red circle to a desired color. I used the code below to change the other colors:

In the form itself:

```
menuStrip1.Renderer = new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(new MenuStripColorTable());
```

The class:

```
class MenuStripColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    private Color backColor = (Color) new ColorConverter().ConvertFromString("#333333");

    //menu item background en border
    public override Color MenuItemBorder
    {  
        get{ return Color.White; }
    }

    public override Color MenuStripGradientBegin
    {
        get { return backColor; }
    }
    ....
```

Any idea what I should override, or change?

Comment: this is part o the menu item. it's the location of the picture box for the icon. hope this help you find it. in WPF it's part of the menu item too.

Comment: Aha, I overrided the Image Gradiant properties to transparant, and that did the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding the folowing code I succesfully made teh white squares transparant:

Render class for menustrip:

```
public override Color ImageMarginGradientBegin
{
   get { return Color.Transparent; }
}
public override Color ImageMarginGradientMiddle
{
   get { return Color.Transparent; }
}
public override Color ImageMarginGradientEnd
{
   get { return Color.Transparent; }
}
```

Altho the text isn't aligned to the left. But that's not that much of a problem. Credit to Franck aswell!

Comment: Just mark it as and correct answer and close the tread it will help to others

Comment: I can't choose my own answer as the best, I have to wait 2 days first